# Xcode - Can't get Jquery to work in local html file

Tags: jquery, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a local html file in a UIWebView with an external jquery file. 
I have put both html and jquery file in the resources folder, but I can not get it to work. The animation from jquery works great in a web browser.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your html file loads fine? How are you referencing jQuery inside the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

I think there exist the possibilitythat jQuery is not being copied inside your app contents, check it out in the targets under the elements that are not compiled (or see if is in the compilable files and move it to copy only).

Comment: Yes, JS files default to being "compiled" when imported to XCode.  THis is likely the problem.  Marking them as not compiled should allow them to be copied into your bundle like a normal asset file.

Comment: To add to what tyoc213 already mention, steps to do this in xcode4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959941/how-to-add-javascript-file-to-xcode4