# How to add javascript file to Xcode4

Tags: javascript, xcode4, xcode3to4

I worked with javascript files within Xcode3 before and everything is great, you just need to copy .js into remove the JavaScript file from the Compile Sources build phase and add it to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase just as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017937/how-to-add-js-file-to-my-xcode-project)

the problem now is how do I do the same thing in Xcode4, I can't seem to find the place to do that.

Help please, Thankz all in advance.
Pondd

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have a check here

1. Project Navigator (Cmd + 1)
2. Select your project
3. Select target
4. Select "Build Phases" tab, there you will get your desire sections.

Comment: * add desired js file to copy bundle resources and remove from compile sources